# Error from security review

Tags: appexchange, security-review, checkmarx

```
if(dupObjDel !=null && dupObjDel.size() > 0 ) {  
    if(isSafeObjectDel( dupObjDel ) ) {               
        delete dupObjDel;  // ERROR in this line
    }                  
}

public static boolean isSafeObjectDel(List<sobject> delId) {
     boolean result=false;
     Sobject del =delId[0];
     String objName= del.id.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName();
     return isDeletable(objName);

}

public static Boolean isDeletable(String sObjectType)
{
    SObjectType schemaType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectType);
    return (schemaType.getDescribe().isAccessible() && schemaType.getDescribe().isDeletable() && schemaType.getDescribe().isMergeable());
}
```

**ERROR Object: dupobjdel in file: /classes/CustomMerge.cls**

Send this code to checkmarks. Error:

> CRUD Delete error from security review.

Comment: Seems like a false positive to me, though I'll admit that I've not used the checkmarx security scanner myself. The only thing I can think of that wouldn't make this a false positive is if Salesforce wants you to check if the running user has access to all of the records you're trying to delete.

Comment: On a different note you can probably do away with that secondary `isDeletable()` method. The `getSObjectType()` method of the `List` class can fetch the type, and then you can call `getDescribe()` on that directly (which is faster than `getGlobalDescribe()`). Store the result in a variable, and then you'll be able to call `isAccessible()`, `isDeletable()`, etc... a bit more efficiently too. The only situation I can think of where this wouldn't be safe is if you tried to do this on a `List<SObject>` that contained more than one type of `SObject`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a false positive. In general, Checkmarx is not going to be able to understand patterns like this, given our current queries for CRUD/FLS.